On lead conversion, create Account, Opportunity, and Contact
I need help, please. I'm starting with Salesforce, and I need that when converting a lead, an account and an opportunity are automatically created. This opportunity should contain specific details, and the account should as well. Additionally, a contact with a name and phone number should also be automatically created. In other words, when converting a lead, I want it to first require me to complete all these things I mentioned. How can I do this? With Flow Builder? Process Builder? Thank you.

Process builder is being sunset, so definitely not that one. This help page seems to suggest that converting a lead can create all 3 without any customization on your part (though you may need to adjust some settings).

Also, for getting started with Salesforce (or even just learning a new part of Salesforce), https://trailhead.salesforce.com is the recommended resource. Typing in "Lead Conversion" over there turns up the Leads and Opportunities Module, which at first blush seems like it would be helpful.

thank Derek @DerekF

Take a look at Lead Conversion field mapping where fields on Lead can be used as the source to set fields on account, contact, opportunity

@cropredy Thanks!! That's exactly what I'm looking for, to have the fields on the lead used as the source for fields on the account, contact, and opportunity. There are some fields that are not mapped by default, and I would like them to be.

You are in luck! All three of these things will natively be created when converting a Lead. If you have custom fields that you want to include, make sure that you add those to your Lead object as well as whatever other object (Account, Contact, Opportunity) the field is relevant to. Additionally, after you create the custom fields, you will need to map them on conversion.
If you want to make fields required before conversion, you would need to used a validation rule and enforce it on conversion.

Hello, thank you so much! Your help and information were very valuable!
